# Calling back from a child class to the parent class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class that downloads some data from the web. Obviously this can take some time.

```
getTheData = [[GetData alloc] init]; 
[getTheData downloadData];// makes the connection to a URL, parses and writes data to an    
array. 
NSString * strHolder = [getTheData.ArrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:0];
```

If I call all that code in that order then I will get an array out of bounds error. Is there some way in Objective C I can get the GetData class to call back to the parent calling class to tell it that the data download has been completed etc so i can then read from the array and do other tasks than i need to do?

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: Implement the delegate pattern, extra points for a formal protocol.

Answer (score 1):

In your `GetData` class, create an `initWithParent:` constructor; store the reference to the parent, and call one of its methods when you're done downloading.